# SQL query returning the same result over and over

Tags: php, mysql

I have one query searching for the usernames and whether a user follows them. The results of that one are displayed in a while loop. In that loop I have another query that will see how many people are following that user. The problem is that it will show the same numbers for all the result. It's like it runs the query only once or so. Here's the code:

```
<?php 
    $req = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users, follows WHERE follows.userId = ?     AND follows.followerId = users.userId ORDER BY users.username");
              $req->execute(array($userId));
              while($data = $req->fetch()){

                ?>
                  <p>
                    <img src="files/useruploads/<?php echo $data['profilePic']; ?>" class="left" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border-radius: 900px;" alt=""/>
                    <a href="<?php echo $data['username']; ?>/"><?php echo $data['username']; ?></a><br>
                    <?php
                    $followers = $db->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS followers FROM follows WHERE follows.followerId = ?");
                    $followers->execute(array($data["userId"]));
                    if($date = $followers->fetch()){
                      $totFollowers = $date["followers"];
                    }
                    ?>
                    <span class="grey-text"><?php echo $totFollowers; ?></span>
                  </p>
                <?php
              }
              ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace code with your inner query with this :

```
$followers = $db->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS followers FROM follows WHERE follows.userId = ?");
```

Expected result should come.

Comment: No, that doesn't work, i use 'userId' in the follows table to identify the person who is following someone and 'followerId' for the person who is being followed.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have no errors in query string.

Try replacing following code

```
if($date = $followers->fetch()){
                      $totFollowers = $date["followers"];
                    }
```

with

```
while($date = $followers->fetch()){
                      $totFollowers = $date["followers"];
                    }
```

Comment: How about this one ?

$followers->execute(array($data["userId"]));

                    $date = $followers->fetchAll());

foreach($date AS $Key=>$Value){

                      $totFollowers = $Value["followers"];

                    }